# how to move each div into another

Tags: jquery, html

I have `div.my-div` in containers. How can I move this `div` from container to section in each section?

```
<section>
   <div class="container">container
       <div class="my-div">my div</div>
   </div>
</section>

<section>
   <div class="container">container
       <div class="my-div">my div</div>
   </div>
</section>

<section>
   <div class="container">container
       <div class="my-div">my div</div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working Demo**

```js
$('div.my-div').each(function(){
  $(this).closest('section').append($(this))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
   <div class="container">container
       <div class="my-div">my div</div>
   </div>
</section>

<section>
   <div class="container">container
       <div class="my-div">my div</div>
   </div>
</section>

<section>
   <div class="container">container
       <div class="my-div">my div</div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @AndreyShandrov Always glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following.

```js
$('.my-div').each(function () {
    $(this).closest('section').append(this.outerHTML);
    $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
   <div class="container">container
       <div class="my-div">my div</div>
   </div>
</section>

<section>
   <div class="container">container
       <div class="my-div">my div</div>
   </div>
</section>

<section>
   <div class="container">container
       <div class="my-div">my div</div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can find the parent section of each `my-div` and use `.append()` to move div to its parent section.

```js
$(function(){
  $('section div.container div.my-div').each(function(){
    $(this).closest('section').append($(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
   <div class="container">container
       <div class="my-div">my div</div>
   </div>
</section>

<section>
   <div class="container">container
       <div class="my-div">my div</div>
   </div>
</section>

<section>
   <div class="container">container
       <div class="my-div">my div</div>
   </div>
</section>
```